# How to put scan area for QR code scan as well as edittext in single layout in android?

Tags: android

I have to make an application which scans the QR code.But, I have to keep two options in the particular screen. User can either scan QR code or directly enter the number in edit text given in same screen.Now, my question is how to put both views i.e. scan area as well as edit text in single xml file??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source project

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

to get this done. By customizing the project.